# I own a 1989 Mercedes 560sec that has rpm surges for no real reason

Tags: transmission, mercedes-benz

It happens once or twice a month, I could be doing 60 mph, and its almost redlining at 5000 rpm!. Once the vehicle gets to normal operating temperature, and I turn it off for a few minutes and turn it back on, I cannot go over 20 mph without the vehicle wanting to redline. I have to let the car cool down over night so that I can drive it no more that 60 mph and not for long distances (no more than 9 or 10 miles) It will do this for 10 days then suddenly it it just stops and runs the way it is supposed to.  Can not figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Sounds like the transmission, is this an automatic?

Comment: @cdunn - I'd almost guarantee it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a vacuum pipe that goes from the engine inlet manifold to the transmission.  I have seen symptoms a little like this caused by damage to this pipe on a similar aged car.